# DNS 301 redirect issue

Tags: dns, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I implemented a DNS-level 301 redirect in my [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/) console, which redirected my old sub-domain `assets.websitename.com` to `websitename.com/assets`.

However, when trying to access `assets.websitename.com/css/main.css`, the client will be redirected to `websitename.com/css/main.css/assets`. I intended to redirect the user to `websitename.com/assets/css/main.css`.

So my question is:

> How can I properly configure the 301 redirect?

Comment: You most likely need a rewrite rule, regardless of which web server you're running. Otherwise, you'll have to handle this in the (backend) application itself - mapping the url via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apache**
If using .htaccess or similar in Apache web server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} assets.websitename.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://websitename.com/assets/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Namecheap**
Since you're using the Namecheap control panel, try this:
Make sure you have a slash at the end of the IP Address / URL box.  So it should look like this:

```
HOSTNAME   IPADDRESS/URL                     REDIRECTTYPE    
assets     http://websitename.com/assets/    URL Redirect
```

notice the slash at the end of `http://websitename.com/assets/`

Comment: The 301 redirect is being done in the DNS management console of my domain, not using apache.

Comment: Who is your domain registrar?

Comment: Modified the answer to include a solution for namecheap url redirect control panel

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem!